# Stretching an image with lastly available pixels(background)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, opencv

I've an image of shape (768,576,3) and I want to Resize it into (1100,1100,3). But not in a usual way. 
[image: Source Image]

The above image has to be padded three sides(top, right left) with their near by pixel values like the below image.
[image: Destination Image]

It is like stretching the image from three sides. How to achieve this programmatically using opencv, numpy or any other way?

Comment: Draw a vertical line just to the left of the subject's arm and take the strip of background to the left of that and make it wider. Do the same on the right side. At the top, draw a horizontal line just above subject's head and take the part above that and make it taller. Paste all the new wide, tall parts onto a new, empty black canvas to touch the left, right and top edge and at each location select the lightest pixel. Paste the original image in at the centre along the bottom edge.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am looking for a programmatical approach.

Comment: That's an algorithm you can program.

Comment: Your images aren't the sizes you say. The first is 236x236 which is square and nothing like 768x576. The second is 297x348, so nothing like the square 1100x1100 you claim in the text. Please make sure the information you supply is correct if you want people to help you. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I just uploaded the sample images without worrying about dimensions. I should've shared the with correct dimensions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cv2.copyMakeBorder(). It has multiple options for the padding flag.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html

Comment: It is not giving desired results. The appended part is distinguishable.